# Highlight and comment in a web page and send them automatically to Evernote in a seamless way?

Tags: if-this-then-that, evernote, synchronization, diigo, highlight

Right now, I am trying a service called [diigo](https://www.diigo.com/) that allows me to highlight and comment any web page I come across. I also use an [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) recipe to send the highlighted URL's page to an [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) notebook.

But what I would really like to do is to send the highlighted text and comment and not the URL to Evernote, so that I could search for everything in one place.

How can I do this seamlessly?

Comment: I am not doing this seamlessly. But since Diigo has a mode that shows every underline and comment on a page, I simply select them with the mouse and use Evernote WebClipper to do the copy pasting. Not ideal but good enough until a better solution arises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, but I have found a solution. I used IFTTT to create a recipe with Todoist and Evernote. Upon installing the Todoist Chrome Extension, I can highlight things, pull up a secondary menu (right-click for most people), and click "Add to Todoist". IFTTT then sends that new item to the end of a note in Evernote, for me to sit down and organize when I have time later.

While not the preferred method, it is the method that works best.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are trying to reinvent the wheel?  Why not use Evernote web clipper which does exactly that https://evernote.com/webclipper/

Comment: Evernote notes are not associated with the page if I visit it a few months from now. I like having things in front of me if at all possible.

Comment: I also want to send only the highlights and comments to Evernote, not the whole text. And this is not possible with WebClipper.